# How do I print using getText from a page object model with log4j?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, log4j, webdriver

I am coding some automated tests using the Selenium Webdriver in Netbeans. I have a pretty simple test, and I am implementing page objects. My trouble is here:

- I *previously* had this code:

  ```
  //Click the Timing Parts subcategory
  WebElement PartSubcategory = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Timing Parts & Camshafts')]"));
  PartSubcategory.click();
  logger.info("Found subcategory: "+PartSubcategory.getText());
  ```
- And, after implementing page object model, it looks like this.

**Page object:**

```
    public class findPartSubcategory {
    private static WebElement element = null;

    //Click the Timing Parts subcategory
    public static WebElement PartSubcategory(WebDriver driver)
            {
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Timing Parts & Camshafts')]"));
        return element;
            }        
     }
```

**Test code:**

```
    //Click the Timing Parts subcategory
    findPartSubcategory.PartSubcategory(driver).click();
    logger.info("Found subcategory: "+findPartCategory.getText());
```

So, the compile error is in getText(), "Cannot find symbol method getText()". I am guessing it's because I am not printing out a properly declared variable, but a page object class.

So how do I get to print what it found for that page object? Yes, I am using log4j ver. 1

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Fixed title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a compilation error.  Trying to reference `findPartCategory.PartCategory` which does not exist.

Change

```
findPartCategory.PartCategory(driver).click();
```

To

```
findPartCategory.PartSubcategory(driver).click();
```

You are also trying to call `getText()` on your `findPartSubcategory` class and I assume you want to call that on the WebElement.

```html
WebElement element = findPartSubcategory.PartSubcategory(driver);
element.click();
logger.info("Found subcategory: "+ element.getText());
```

That should achieve the same functionality as your old code.